RStudio - How to navigate files pane with arrow keys?
In RStudio, one can focus the history tab using ctrl/cmd + 4 and then use arrow keys to navigate and enter to select commands. But when focusing the files pane with ctrl/cmd + 5, I see no such option. Is there a way to navigate the files pane with arrow keys?
I know that one can use the rstudioapi like in this question, and use list.files(), and change the working directory from the console, and use ctrl/cmd + . to go to a file, and use relative paths within a project. But I still want arrow keys, just like in the history tab. I haven't found a way to select/highlight folders, either by using the mouse or by tabbing to it.
Would also welcome similar solutions for the environment tab. Thanks!
Edit: R Version 4.4.1, Rstudio version 2024.04.2, Windows 10

After ctrl/cmd + 5, use the tab key to navigate through the files pane options (and shift + tab in reverse order), and once in the files list window, you can use up/down arrow keys.
EDIT
If Files pane is already open and tab does not work, use ctrl/cmd + 4 and again ctrl/cmd + 5 to get the focus again. This works on Linux.
On  Windows, I could not use tab either, even after the trick above. You can then use the F6 key to switch between the 4 main panes and get the focus on the Files pane, using the tab key works in this case.
The navigation with arrow keys is quite limited, you have to select the file you want and go back to the options above (e.g. More > Open Selected in Source Pane) with shift + tab. There is no way to enter a folder.

Hm, this isn't working for me. If I am in the source pane and hit ctrl/cmd + 5 it opens the files pane, but the cursor remains in the source. If I then push tab, it moves the cursor within the script. Edited the question to include os and R version if that matters.

see the edit for additional options

Thanks for the followup. This is indeed working as you describe, and seems to be all RStudio offers for this. But it is unfortunately also prohibitively onerous. I wonder if there might be workarounds to make it function more like the file explorer in VSCodium. I'm going to leave this post unanswered for now and see if any workarounds come up, but let me know if that's not how this is supposed to work.
